# Making a wave animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make audio wave animation. What is wrong with this code?
I tried to change translate to scale but it didn't work. Could someone give me a link to some exercises of animation?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: wave 2s linear infinite;
}
.a1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.a2 {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.a3 {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.a4 {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
.a5 {
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
@keyframes wave {
  0%, 50%, 75%, 100% {
    height: 5px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    height: 30px;
    transform: translateY(15px);
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="a1"></span>
  <span class="a2"></span>
  <span class="a3"></span>
  <span class="a4"></span>
  <span class="a5"></span>
</div>
```

wave , code is working but it does not appear as a wave

Comment: animate.css is quite good, google it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the up and down movement of the elements by animating the [transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) instead of the height of the elements.

You can use the scaleY() function to make the elements grow on the Y axis (height).

Example :

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: wave 2s linear infinite;
}
.a1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.a2 {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.a3 {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.a4 {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
.a5 {
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
@keyframes wave {
  0%, 50%{
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleY(4);
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="a1"></span>
  <span class="a2"></span>
  <span class="a3"></span>
  <span class="a4"></span>
  <span class="a5"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works , but why it does not work by using translate Y ?

Comment: @LCTS `translateY` will make the element move on the Y axis whereas `scaleY` will make it grow or shrink on the Y axis.