# How to make wave animation in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

I want to create wave animation with 3-4 waves in HTML.
and also I want to make responsive for mobile,tablet etc.

I have also attached the image which I want to use as wave.

Comment: Ok, sounds great - what have you got so far?

Comment: Hey Harsh, please read these: [ask] and [mcve], then edit your question accordingly. As is, your question isn't even a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the up and down movement of the elements by animating the transform property instead of the height of the elements.

You can use the scaleY() function to make the elements grow on the Y axis (height).

[Making a wave animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304159/making-a-wave-animation)